# Draw a graph where $f(x) < 0$ and $f'(x) > 0$ for the $x$-values between $3$ and $7$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Question: Draw a graph where $f(x) < 0$ and $f'(x) > 0$ for the $x$-values between $3$ and $7$.

I don't really understand how to plot this into a graph.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What does it mean for a function $f$ to have $f(x)<0$? Then, what does it mean for the same function to have $f'(x)>0$?

Comment: Plot a suitable straight line!

Answer (score 1):

Some quick thoughts and hints:

1. Keep in mind the geometric interpretation of a derivative for basic functions, ie. $f'(x)$ says something about the slope of the curve.
2. Try plotting a simple function like, $x^2$, and look at where it has positive and negative derivative. Then simply shift the function (linearly) so that it meets the criteria for your question.